How to derive any householder method for a vector of nonlinear functions f(x) of a vector of variables x
I'm able to do this for a scalar function of a scalar:
display2d:false$
n:3$
x + n*diff(1/f(x), x, n-1)/diff(1/f(x), x, n);
subst('diff(f(x), x, 1)=J, %);
subst('diff(f(x), x, 2)=H, %);
subst('diff(f(x), x, 3)=T, %);

How can I do it for a vector function with J being a 2-dimensional matrix and H being a 3-dimensional matrix and so on?
Motivation:
Householder methods include Newton's method with n=1.
N=2 is Halley's method.
The wikipedia page only tells us, how to derive the method for scalar functions -- for a system of with a single equation and a single unknown.
I know how to apply Newton's method to systems of equations.
But for higher order householder methods I'm lost.
Higher order methods are supposed to converge quicker or converge where lower order methods don't.
As with automatic differentiation the calculation of higher order derivatives is done very easily, I want to explore these higher order methods.
Many companies are still doing by-hand-differentiation and I think because of this they are scared of even calculating Jacobians and don't dare to touch calculating Hessians.
PS.
I'm not a mathematician. Earlier I did not have any success in posting my questions on the matching math site of stackoverflow.

This seems like an interesting problem, but it would help others help you if you say more about what operation is implemented here. My advice is to give a link to a description of the general method so that people understand what is the desired outcome, i.e., to say more about what is supposed to happen if it is working the way that you want, and how that differs from the result you are getting now.

Frank, thanks for the additional information. I will take a look at it later today. In the meantime, let me suggest that Maxima-specific questions, especially those needing some discussion, might find a suitable audience on the maxima-discuss mailing list. See: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/maxima-discuss

I looked at the Wikipedia page about it so now I understand a little better about the problem. I think the next step is to state the update formula in terms of noncommutative operations so that it can be applied to multidimensional functions. For example, a . inverse(b) instead of a*b and inverse(b) instead of 1/b for any terms a and b in the formula. It seems like we might want to replace diff(inverse(f)) with inverse(diff(f)) which is, if I remember from my analysis class correctly, an identity (part of the inverse function theorem if I'm not mistaken).

Leaving this for reference: https://optimization-online.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/03/1610.pdf which presents generalizations of Halley's method to multidimensional problems. I will take a closer look and see how that stuff might be implemented.

I've implemented a generalized Halley method in Maxima. This is a family of second order methods; I didn't try to take third order derivatives into account. It is pretty straightforward in Maxima. If there's interest in generating code for other languages, e.g. Python, let's discuss that. Here's a link to what I came up with. https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages/tree/master/robert-dodier/generalized_halley
